# Network says Dom Content Loaded. Console.log doesn't log to developer console. Debugger doesn't hit. Function is not called

Tags: javascript, event-listener, domcontentloaded

I have double checked spelling. This file is named. Index.js and it is in the src folder.Really not sure why console.log and debugger are not working. Network tab in chrome developer tools says the dom content loaded. I am befuddled why none of my code is running in the console.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
  debugger
  fetchAllBeers();
});

function fetchAllBeers() {

  const beerContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0]
  debugger
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/beers")
    .then(resp) => resp.json()
    .then(function(data) {
      data.forEach(beer => {

        beerContainer.innerHTML += renderABeer(beer);

      });
    })
}

function renderABeer(beer) {

  return `<ul class="list-group">
      <h1>Beer Name</h1>
      <img src="<add beer img url here>">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Like</button>
      <span>add number of likes here</span>
    </li>
  </ul>`
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <ul class="list-group" id="list-group">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>`

</html>
```

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)"`

Answer (score 0):

The only rational explanation is that your code is being executed after the DOMContentLoaded event is fired. Consider putting the script in the `<head>` tag to ensure it runs before the body is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are actual issues in your code. I copy + pasted into the snippet editor what you had posted and there was an error.

In the future, if you use the editor here to post your code, you may be able to more quickly catch errors.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
  debugger
  fetchAllBeers();
});

function fetchAllBeers() {

  const beerContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0]
  debugger
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/beers")
    .then((resp) => resp.json()) // FIX THIS LINE
    .then(function(data) {
      data.forEach(beer => {

        beerContainer.innerHTML += renderABeer(beer);

      });
    })
}
```

[image]